# Clonezilla script fails: Unable to find target hard drive

Tags: windows-11, surface-pro, clonezilla

I have saved a disk to an image.

I can restore this image to a new drive when I use the manual approach where Clonezilla asks all these questions.

I answer them using the Beginner Mode.
I don't change anything or do anything fancy.

Now I am trying to automatically deploy this image using a script:

```
#
set prefix=/boot/grub/
set default="0"
set timeout="5"
set hidden_timeout_quiet=false

if loadfont $prefix/unicode.pf2; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  insmod efi_gop
  insmod efi_uga
  insmod gfxterm
  terminal_output gfxterm
fi

if background_image $prefix/logo-jpik.png; then
  set color_normal=black/black
  set color_highlight=red/black
else
  set color_normal=cyan/blue
  set color_highlight=white/blue
fi


menuentry "Apply Software Image from Pendrive"{
search --set -f /live/vmlinuz
linux /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user hostname=JPSC config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=pt vga=791 ip= nosplash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1 ocs_live_batch="no" ocs_prerun="ln -s /lib/live/mount/medium/Image/ /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -e1 auto -e2 -batch -r -j2 -scr -p poweroff restoredisk Image/ mmcblk0" ocs_live_extra_param=""
echo "Loading Clonezilla..."
initrd /live/initrd.img
}
```

Using this script, I get the follow error:

"Unable to find target hard drive"

Does anybody know why and can tell me what I need to change?

Thank you!

Here is what my image files look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

I needed to edit \boot\grub\grub.cfg from this version...

linux /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user hostname=JPSC config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=pt vga=791 ip= nosplash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1 ocs_live_batch="no" ocs_prerun="ln -s /lib/live/mount/medium/Image/ /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -e1 auto -e2 -batch -r -j2 -scr -p poweroff restoredisk Image/ mmcblk0" ocs_live_extra_param=""

... to this:

linux /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user hostname=JPSC config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=pt vga=791 ip= nosplash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1 ocs_live_batch="no" ocs_prerun="ln -s /lib/live/mount/medium/Image/ /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -e1 auto -e2 -batch -r -j2 -scr -p poweroff restoredisk Image/ nvme0n1" ocs_live_extra_param=""